# snakemake wrapper: pointing wildcard to a list either config.yaml or txt

Tags: python, list, snakemake

I am trying to use the following snakemake wrapper:

```
rule get_fastq_pe:
    output:
        # the wildcard name must be accession, pointing to an SRA number
        "data/{accession}_1.fastq",
        "data/{accession}_2.fastq"
    params:
        # optional extra arguments
        extra=""
    threads: 6  # defaults to 6
    wrapper:
        "0.73.0/bio/sra-tools/fasterq-dump"
```

How would you direct accession to multiple SRR accessions either in a txt file or config.yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, specify all the SRR you need in a yaml file `SRR.yml`:

```
SRR:
  - SRR1234
  - SRR5678
  - SRR2468
  - SRR1357
```

Then in your Snakefile, load the yaml file with the keyword `configfile:`:

```
configfile: "SRR.yml"
```

define a rule all to trigger the creation of all necessary files:

```
rule all:
    input: expand("data/{accession}_{RF}.fastq", accession=config["SRR"], RF=["1","2"])
```

then add your rule:

```
rule get_fastq_pe:
    output:
        # the wildcard name must be accession, pointing to an SRA number
        "data/{accession}_1.fastq",
        "data/{accession}_2.fastq"
    params:
        # optional extra arguments
        extra=""
    threads: 6  # defaults to 6
    wrapper:
        "0.73.0/bio/sra-tools/fasterq-dump"
```

Comment: Very helpful and obvious.  Thanks.  I didn't have or understand that I needed a rule all.  Was trying to add something similar to the rule get_fastq_pe output, or in params.